# Installing Team Foundation Server 2010 with SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: installation, sharepoint-2010, team-foundation-server

Is it possible to install TFS 2010 with SharePoint Foundation 2010? If yes is there any installation guide?

UPDATE (05. February 2010):

I found some useful help in Internet. For example this [one](http://myalmblog.com/2010/12/20/installing-tfs2010-with-sharepoint-foundation-2010/). The problem is that I can't use the standard port 80 for Web Application because this one is already assigned to my web page. So what is to do to use other port? Can I use other port or should I use bindings?

Best Regards

Anton Kalcik

Comment: There is information on [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/f79769d4-9c3d-4303-9c85-78a70f4ded6c), which is the second hit from a quick [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22tfs+2010%22+%22sharepoint+2010%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a).

Comment: I ask explicit about SharePoint Foundation 2010 (it is not the same as SharePoint 2010) and searching also for installation guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to install TFS 2010 with SharePoint Foundation 2010. There isn't out any official installation guide, but there are some out there (for example this [one](http://myalmblog.com/2010/12/20/installing-tfs2010-with-sharepoint-foundation-2010)). It is also possible to use some of the installation guides which describes TFS integration with SharePoint 2010. You can get also more information in my cross post on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/87b784d1-6103-4dfa-8cdf-73321ccf4a44).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I created a [video on my blog](http://elhajj.wordpress.com/2011/05/19/how-to-install-and-configure-moss-2010-for-tfs-2010/) that walks you through it:

EDIT: Ah, wait. Foundation. My video is for MOSS 2010. Should still work. For port 80 issue, I would not use a non 80 port. If you do, all your users will have to add the port number to URLs. Use 80 or setup host headers.